# SQL/PHP Conditional SELECT and UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to return 5 unused values from the `codes` column of the table below and then set `used` in the related row to 1.

```
|--- codes ---| | used |
| FIomQVu71l  | |   0  |
| 4TW0lwLWNK  | |   0  |
| SjzLB2Shzr  | |   0  |
| uTWJrtCgh4  | |   0  |
| tLwOwYGz5R  | |   0  |
| byEhzYMWJG  | |   0  |
| XFBmGzDGIR  | |   0  |
```

I've managed to get the code working to output 5 random values from `codes` where used = 0

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT codes FROM code_table WHERE used =0 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 5";
$records = mysql_query($sql, $connection);
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($records)){
echo "Code: " . $rows['codes'] . "<br />";
?>
```

But now I'm lost as to how to update the `used` value for each output `codes`. All of my attempts have updated every single instance of `used` to 1 rather than just the instances associated with the 5 `codes`

Comment: Why do you need to return the codes first?

Comment: The full code basically takes a user entered value, checks it exists in a table and then displays 5 random codes from another table to the user - I then need to mark those codes as `used` so that when the next user enters a value, the 5 random codes they are given are pulled from those not marked as used.

Comment: . . I would approach the logic differently.  I would update the table to be used first -- storing a unique user or session identifier instead of just a flag.  Then I'd fetch back the rows "reserved" by the user.

Comment: Also `ORDER BY rand()` can have adverse performance effects. You should look at some [alternatives](http://www.roberthartung.de/mysql-order-by-rand-a-case-study-of-alternatives/)

Answer (score 0):

You could store the rows in a temporary table.  Note that this is not entirely concurrency safe.  If another query comes between the `insert` and the `update`, it might grab the same rows.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp_codes (codes varchar(50));

-- Get five new rows
INSERT INTO tmp_codes
        (codes)
SELECT  codes
FROM    code_table
WHERE   used = 0
ORDER BY
        rand()
LIMIT   5;

-- Update the five rows
UPDATE  code_table
SET     used = 1
WHERE   codes in
        (
        SELECT  codes
        FROM    tmp_codes
        );

-- Return to application
SELECT  codes
FROM    tmp_codes;

DROP TABLE tmp_codes;
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a9ff12/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

You should execute an update query:

```
$sql = "SELECT codes FROM code_table WHERE used =0 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 5";
$records = mysql_query($sql, $connection);
$codes = array();
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($records)){
    echo "Code: " . $rows['codes'] . "<br />";
    $codes[] = "'" . $rows['codes'] . "'";
}
$updateSql = "UPDATE code_table SET used = 1 WHERE codes in(" . implode (',' , $codes ) . ")";
$res = mysql_query($updateSql, $connection);
```

Comment: Thanks Noy. This looks like exactly what I'm trying to do, but it doesn't seem to be working. The page wasn't loading, so I changed the array definition to $codes = Array(); and it now it loads and my original code runs fine, but I'm still not seeing any changes to the `used` values

Comment: You might want to look into code uniqueness? This piece of code may lead to two users (running through the logic at the same time) being served the same code.

Comment: @BillRoberts can you please echo $updateSql and try to run the results in mysql console \ phpmyadmin?